# How to make some Multiple row in Table

Tags: tables, multirow

I would like create a table with multiple rows in column # 1, # 2 and # 3. Here is a table that I made by not using the `\multirow` command. How to use `\multirow` for this table:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Kepakaran dan tugas tim pengusul}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|l|}
\hline
No. & Nama Pengusul & Kepakaran  & Tugas \\ \hline
    &                 &                           & - Disain sistem dan peralatan \\
    &                 &                           & - Supervisi manufaktur sistem \\ 
 1  & Fauzan, ST., MT & Teknik Mesin - Manufaktur & - Menjalankan proses produksi \\ 
    &                 &                           & - Evaluasi kegiatan \\ 
\hline   
   &                                  &                                    & - Akuisisi data \\
   &                                  &                                    & - Estimasi Biaya \\ 
 2 &  Muhammad Ikhwanus, ST., M.Eng.  &  Bidang Elektronika - Informatika  & - Evaluasi kegiatan \\ 
   &                                  &                                    & - Dokumentasi \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular}

\end{table}
```

Answer (score 4):

It is not clear to me, what benefit you like to achieve with `multirow` package. To my taste is better to redesign table in the following form:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
    \newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabitemize}{itemize}{1}% <-- defined new list
\setlist[tabitemize]{nosep,     % <-- new list setup
                     topsep     = 0pt               ,
                     partopsep  = 0pt               ,
                     leftmargin = *                 ,
                     label      = -                 ,
                     before     = \vspace{-0.6\baselineskip}   ,
                     after      = \vspace{-\baselineskip}
                     }
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Kepakaran dan tugas tim pengusul}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c P{0.25\linewidth} P{0.25\linewidth} P{0.35\linewidth} }
    \toprule
No. & Nama Pengusul & Kepakaran & Tugas                         \\ 
    \midrule
 1  &Fauzan, ST., MT&   \begin{tabitemize}
                    \item   Teknik Mesin 
                    \item   Manufaktur
                        \end{tabitemize}

                                 &   \begin{tabitemize}
                                \item   Disain sistem dan peralatan
                                \item   Supervisi manufaktur sistem
                                \item   Menjalankan proses produksi
                                \item   Evaluasi kegiatan
                                    \end{tabitemize}               \\
    \midrule
 2  &  Muhammad Ikhwanus, ST., M.Eng.  
                    &  \begin{tabitemize}
                    \item   Bidang Elektronika 
                    \item   Informatika  
                        \end{tabitemize}
                                 &   \begin{tabitemize}
                                \item   Akuisisi data
                                \item   Estimasi Biaya
                                \item   Evaluasi kegiatan           
                                \item   Dokumentasi                 
                                    \end{tabitemize}               \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

In above code in the last column is used list `itemize` defined by help of package `enumitem`. For profesional look I use rules from package `booktabs` and delete vertical lines.

If instead of second `\midrule` you use `\addlinespace`, than table becomes even better:

[image]

*Addendum:*
in case, that you like to have column headers bold and centered:

[image]

Added is package `makecell` and redefined `theadfont` to

```
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries\normalsize}
```

and the first bale row to:

```
\thead{No.} & \thead{Nama Pengusul} & \thead{Kepakaran} & \thead{Tugas}\\
```

Answer (score 1):

Use with package `multirow`

```
\multirow{nrows}{width}{content}
```

**nrows**: number of rows to be spanned. (Numbers can be positive or negative).

**width**: width of the content.

**content**: the text that will be printed

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Kepakaran dan tugas tim pengusul}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|l|}
\hline
No. & Nama Pengusul & Kepakaran  & Tugas \\ \hline
    &                 &                           & - Disain sistem dan peralatan \\
    &                 &                           & - Supervisi manufaktur sistem \\
 \multirow{1}{*}{1}   &  \multirow{0}{90pt}{Fauzan, ST., MT} &  \multirow{0}{90pt}{Teknik Mesin - Manufaktur} & - Menjalankan proses produksi \\
    &                 &                           & - Evaluasi kegiatan \\
\hline
   &                                  &                                    & - Akuisisi data \\
   &                                  &                                    & - Estimasi Biaya \\
 \multirow{1}{*}{2} &   \multirow{-2}{90pt}{Muhammad Ikhwanus, ST., M.Eng.}  &   \multirow{-2}{90pt}{Bidang Elektronika - Informatika}  & - Evaluasi kegiatan \\
   &                                  &                                    & - Dokumentasi \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table}
```

Comment: Thank's a lot for your answer Saravanan, It worked nice.  But how can I  create table with only header bold and center?

Comment: use the following coding to make center with bold: \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{No.}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Nama Pengusul}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Kepakaran}}  & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Tugas}} \\ \hline

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need   `multirow` here. You'll obtain, much better results (and simpler code) designing a new `I` column type, based on the `m` type and requiring `enumitem`, which automatically enter an itemize environment on entering a cell, and leaves the environment on leaving the cell, so that you can use the `\item` command inside these columns. In addition I added some vertical padding to the first row, with the `\Gaped` command from `makecell`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} 
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{array,  caption,  makecell}

\newcolumntype{I}[1]{ >{\arraybackslash\itemize[label =\textendash,  wide=0pt, after=\vspace*{-\topsep}]}m{#1}<{\enditemize}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Kepakaran dan tugas tim pengusul}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c| >{\raggedright}m{3cm}|I{3.5cm}|I{5cm}|}
\hline
\Gape[4pt][3pt]{N\textsuperscript{o}}  & Nama Pengusul & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Kepakaran}& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Tugas} \\ \hline
  1 & Fauzan, ST., MT &
  \item Teknik Mesin\item Manufaktur
   & \item Disain sistem dan peralatan
    \item Supervisi manufaktur sistem
    \item Menjalankan proses produksi
    \item Evaluasi kegiatan \\
\hline
  2 & Muhammad Ikhwanus, ST., M.Eng.
  &
  \item Bidang Elektronika
  \item Informatika
  &    \item Akuisisi data
   \item Estimasi Biaya
   \item Evaluasi kegiatan
   \item Dokumentasi \\
   \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Replace your headers with this:

```
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{No.}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Nama Pengusul}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Kepakaran}}  & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Tugas}} \\ \hline
```